# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20 on different drives, can't see Ubuntu drive from Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I have 3 disks, C, D and E.

Initially I had Windows 10 installed on disk C, then I formatted and made a clean install of Ubuntu on disk E. When I start my computer I can choose to boot to Ubuntu or Windows.

When I boot to Ubuntu I can see and access C D and E. When I boot to Windows I can only see and access C and D, E that holds Ubuntu is invisible to me (which was visible and accessible before the Ubuntu install).

Showing disk in disk management, can't do anything but delete the volume.:

[image: Showing disk in disk management, can't do anything but delete the volume.]

Answer (score 1):

Windows don't support natively any Linux Partitions at all so that is the reason why you are not able to access it

Comment: You can sometimes, but not on all systems, get [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) to allow Windows to see Linux formatted partitions.

Comment: the answer is, no without any third-party products you will not be able to access the Partitions. The only way to exchange data between both systems would be to use a FAT32 or with some premises of danger also NTFS but anyhow you will be able to save to the Windows Partition but not wise versa without a helper